Filter nested column in PrimeNG Table (Angular)
So I have a column which is nested e.g. customer.hobbies.favourite. I want to be able to filter based on the favourite.name.
Data Sample:
{
        id: 1000,
        name: 'James Butt',
        country: {
          name: 'Algeria',
          code: 'dz',
        },
        company: 'Benton, John B Jr',
        date: '2015-09-13',
        status: 'unqualified',
        verified: true,
        activity: 17,
        representative: {
          name: 'Ioni Bowcher',
          image: 'ionibowcher.png',
        },
        balance: 70663,
        hobbies: {
          favourite: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: 'football',
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: 'basketball',
            },
          ],
        },
      },

My retrieval of hobbies to have them display
  getHobbies(customer: any): string {
    return customer.hobbies.favourite.map((h: any) => h.name).join(', ');
  }

Hobbies HTML
          <div class="flex align-items-center">
            Hobbies
            <p-columnFilter
              type="text"
              field="hobbies.favourite"
              display="menu"
            />
          </div>

Row
        <td>{{ getHobbies(customer) }}</td>


For example:

If for the Hobbies Column, I filter so that it starts with "football" then it should show James Butt.

If I filter contains "c" then only all rows with cricket would show. In this case Josephine Darakjy


Stackblitz replicating my issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/8xxfhn-hapzpy
Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

With FilterService, you can customize the filter (logic) for the single column.
<div class="flex align-items-center">
  Hobbies
  <p-columnFilter
    type="text"
    field="hobbies.favourite"
    display="menu"
    [showMatchModes]="false"
    [showOperator]="false"
    [showAddButton]="false"
    [matchModeOptions]="{ label: 'Hobbies Contain', value: 'hobbies-contain' }"
    [matchMode]="'hobbies-contain'"
  />
</div>

Register the FilterService into the component and add the filter constraint: "hobbies-contain"
import { FilterService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-filter-advanced-demo',
  templateUrl: 'table-filter-advanced-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule],
  providers: [CustomerService, FilterService],
})
export class TableFilterAdvancedDemo implements OnInit {
  ...

  constructor(
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private filterService: FilterService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    ...

    this.filterService.register('hobbies-contain', (value, filter): boolean => {
      if (filter === undefined || filter === null || filter.trim() === '') {
        return true;
      }

      if (value === undefined || value === null) {
        return false;
      }

      return this.filterFavoriteHobbies(value, filter).length > 0;
    });
  }

  ...
}

However, the global filter won't work as it filters the data with "contains" match mode. The custom filter for hobbies.favourite does not apply to the global filter.
The easiest way is to modify your table data and interface to return the hobbies.favourite as string[] instead of the nested array of objects. Apply the new field: favouriteHobbies to the interface, data and PrimeNG table.
export type CustomerWithFavoriteHobbies = Customer & {
  favouriteHobbies: string[] | null;
} 

customers!: CustomerWithFavoriteHobbies[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.customerService.getCustomersLarge().then((customers) => {
    this.customers = customers.map(x => ({
      ...x,
      favouriteHobbies: x.hobbies?.favourite?.map(y => y.name)
    }));

    this.loading = false;

    this.customers.forEach(
      (customer) => (customer.date = new Date(<Date>customer.date))
    );
  });
}

<p-table
    #dt1
    [value]="customers"
    dataKey="id"
    [rows]="10"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"
    [loading]="loading"
    [paginator]="true"
    [globalFilterFields]="['name', 'country.name', 'representative.name', 'status', 'favouriteHobbies']"
  >
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      ...

      <th style="min-width: 10rem">
        <div class="flex align-items-center">
          Hobbies
          <p-columnFilter
            type="text"
            field="favouriteHobbies"
            display="menu"
            matchMode="contains"
          />
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-customer>
    <tr>
      ...

      <td>
        {{ customer.favouriteHobbies?.join(', ') }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>

  ...

</p-table>

Demo @ StackBlitz

First of all don't use a FN in HTML cause this triggers every change detection " {{ getHobbies(customer) }} " use instead a pipe
"{{ customer.hobbies.favourite | concatHobbies }}", this will only trigger if the value before it will change.
Use PrimeNg FilterSerivce to create your own Filter which can filter nested objects.

You can introduce a new property in customer object. Customer.favouriteHobbies
and set the value as customer.hobbies.favourite.map((h: any) => h.name).join(', ');
so it would look something like this
customer.favouriteHobbies = customer.hobbies.favourite.map((h: any) => h.name).join(', ');

Now normal primeng filter would work and yield the result you wanted
